# How to make valueChangeObserver to use a key stored in the cache

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make the appBar change color depending on which key value from a setting dropDown Menu is selected, I know how to use `valueChangeObserver` with booleans but not with multiple values.

Here's an example of how I used it with my Dark Mode feature in my main file, I'm trying to do this but with a custom list of values that change the theme of the app.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueChangeObserver<bool>(
        cacheKey: ConfigPage.KeyDarkMode,
        defaultValue: true,
        builder: (_, isDarkMode, __) => MaterialApp(
              title: _title,
              theme: isDarkMode
                  ? ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
                      primaryColor: Colors.teal,
                      scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF170635),
                      canvasColor: const Color(0xFF170635),
                    )
                  : ThemeData.light().copyWith(),
              home: const PagPrin(),
            ));
  }
}
```

And here's the DropDown Menu which has a key that I want  to use to change the theme of the app itself

```
Widget buildTheme() => DropDownSettingsTile(
      settingKey: keyTheme,
      title: "Colors ",
      selected: 1,
      values: <int, String>{
        1: 'Select color',
        2: 'White',
        3: 'Brown',
        4: 'Grey',
      },
      onChange: (colors) {/*NOOP*/},
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

ValueChangeObserver is Generic widget class, so you can pass any type instead of bool type.

for your problem you can use string or int, after that handle any color selected with switch case or if else

Comment: Thanks but, how can I turn the key value to a string or int? and then use that string inside the ValueChangeObserver?
Sorry, I'm new to flutter

Comment: ValueChangeObserver <Map<int, String>>(....)

Comment: I just want to understand how to use a switch or if inside of my ValueChangeObserver.